# Stroke order for han-dakuten

Tags: kana, stroke-order

Is there one?  Or does it even matter?  I personally start at the top and go clockwise.  Just curious.

---

**Update:**  I realized the other day that the reason I start at the 12-o'clock position and go clockwise is because this is the same motion (more or less) used when writing あ, お, め, ぬ, の, etc.

Comment: I start at the top and go anti-clockwise.

Comment: @Flaw-san  So do I.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, a han-dakuten isn't a kanji, so I would say that it doesn't matter one way or another. However, the actual kanji  `〇` has a "stroke order" (stroke direction?) of a single stroke starting at the top and going counter-clockwise. ([Link](http://kakijun.main.jp/page/zero01200.html)) So, if `。` does have one, my bet is that's what it is.

Comment: That being said, I always go clockwise...

Comment: Lol!! What kanji is that 〇 btw?

Comment: @Chocolate It's "zero" or "circle" (as in what is used for correcting papers) http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97#.E3.80.87.E3.80.81.E9.9B.B6
It's a relatively new kanji, as these things go, apparently.
Also, I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted: I provided a source to back up what I said, I answered the question, I can't guarantee it's correct, but Comments are not for Answers: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/593/921

Comment: Lol, I don't see why your answer was downvoted either. Well we usually don't call 'zero'/'circle' a kanji so I got a bit confused. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: @Chocolate, It is sort of a grey area, that's true! I remember a big O being drawn with ink and brush on a car commercial once, so I figured there had to be an "official" way of writing it...

Comment: Why does whether han-dakuten is kanji or not matters?  Kana letters have stroke orders, too.

Answer (score 2):

This [blog post](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/moonie-moonie/e/5009c6ccb7dbd9f492cd2a976111e0b7) refers to an elementary school text book for the writing order of a 半濁点. It starts from 6 o'clock and goes around clockwise.

Comment: That is how I learned to write it back in first-grade as well.

Comment: I can agree on that. I also write 。(句点) in same way as well.