# Quotation Mark Stroke Order

Tags: handwriting, punctuation, quotes, stroke-order, stroke-count

How do Japanese people hand-write the Japanese Quotation Marks (「　」)? Is there a correct stroke order?

I am asking specifically about those used in horizontal writing, although I wouldn't mind knowing about the vertical ones too.

Comment: Related:  [Stroke order for han-dakuten](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4183/78)

Comment: Are you asking specifically about those used in horizontal writing?

Comment: @l'électeur Yes, although I wouldn't mind knowing about the vertical ones too.

Comment: For 「, I as a Chinese always go left than down. For 」, I go down and left. I've seen other people write them differently though. Some even write it with two strokes.

Comment: @Sweeper that's the way I've been doing it so far, so I guess I'll just keep  using that method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe the stroke order works as normal, starting from the top down. So with '「' you would write the top horizontal line first then as a separate stroke or carrying on from the left corner of the line do the vertical line.

(In modern writing this is usually done in one stroke but I've seen both styles.)

Then with the other bracket simply do the reverse, the vertical line then the horizontal starting from right to left.

Comment: I think I start writing a vertical line first for the top and bottom in vertical and horizontal writing. But no particular rules for me at the moment.