# Does the handákuten have an official stroke direction?

Tags: stroke-order

Does ゜, the 半濁点 はんだくてん{LHHLLL}, have an official starting point and stroke direction? At http://japanese-lesson.com/characters/hiragana/hiragana_drill/hiragana06_writing.html, they teach to start at the bottom and go clockwise. Is starting at the top and going anticlockwise as incorrect as writing も with the horizontal lines first?

Does any official document touch on this? Do textbooks for native speakers have anything to say on the matter?

(I'm aware an equivalent question was asked nearly a decade ago, but it still hasn't received a definitive answer, so I'm being so bold as to try again.)

Comment: Related: [Stroke order for han-dakuten](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4183/5010)

Comment: You can just add a bounty to the other question...

Comment: This is how first-graders are taught to write 半濁点 in the only Japanese-speaking country in the world, which is why I have great doubts about the "best answer" in the linked Q&A above.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DAbFkCL4_o

Comment: @istrasci I haven't achieved that privilege yet.